# How can I transfer iJoomer app to XCode iPhone simulator?

Tags: itunes, xcode, itunes-store, xcode-simulator

I downloaded iJoomer in iTunes, and I would like to transfer it into XCode's iPhone Simulator so I can run the app there.

Is it possible to transfer an app from iTunes to the iPhone simulator? If so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no.

The reasons are numerous, but the first is that anything compiled to run on a device can not be run in the simulator because the processor architecture is different. The simulator is simulating a device, not emulating a device. Apps run in the simulator are intel x86 binaries, while apps that run on a device are compiled for some version of the ARM processor.